# Finding all .config files

Tags: find, ls

I am new to Linux and on of my projects is to find all .config files.
I made sure to be logged in as root. What command would I run to do this.

Comment: There are a *lot* of config files on your system. Some are labelled with `*.config` and some are not. Some are in your `/etc`, some are in your `/usr`, and some are in your `/home`. Perhaps you could explain a bit more clearly exactly what you are looking for...and why?

Comment: This sounds like homework, and you were not paying attention in class.

Answer (score 0):

From your parent folder on the terminal, you could use find and grep commands:

```
find | grep "\.config"
```

Answer (score 0):

`locate -br \\.config$`

If it is not installed, then previously use `sudo apt install mlocate`